# Is there a way for a bot to find the IP address of my Digital Ocean Server when going through Cloudflare?

Tags: server, digital-ocean, cloudflare

I am a PHP coder but not a server expert so I wondered if anyone could answer the following query.

Is there a way that a bot can determine the IP of my server when it runs through Cloudflare?

Someone suggested that folk could try ftp.domain.com and things like that. I do not have that setup on my server although Cloudflare do set this up automatically for you when you register a domain.

If you are a server expert and wanted to determine the actual IP of a server, how would you go about it?

Thanks.
PS: I do not want my IP public, hence the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Someone that *really* wants to find your server IP address probably can. We're only going to really stop basic lookups from returning your IPs, but we can only proxy web traffic & some records on your domain (mail, for example) may still return your server IP.

We do have some tips on minimizing the probability that someone could find it easily with these [guidelines](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200170166-General-website-security-guidelines).